# C++: Addressing each byte

Tags: c++, windows, pointers

Trying to extract each byte in a short I've created.
While I can print the second (or first) byte, I can't get both.
With my current understanding, this should work. Hoping someone can make it clear to me what the error is here. I'm running this on windows x86, so ILP32 data format.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    short i = 0x1123;
    short* p = &i;
    short* p1 = p;

    p1++;
    
    char c = *p;
    char c1 = *p1;

    cout
        << "Short: " << hex << i << '\n'
        << "p: " << p << '\n'
        << "p1: " << p1 << '\n'
        << "c: " << hex << (unsigned int)c << '\n'
        << "c1: " << hex << (unsigned int)c1 << '\n'
        ;

    return 0;
}
```

```
Output:
Short: 1123
p: 0041FB58
p1: 0041FB56
c: 23
c1: ffffffcc
```

Comment: After the increment, `p1` points **past** the end of `i`. Dereferencing it makes the behavior of that program undefined.

Comment: Thanks guys, managed to infer what was happening from your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fix:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    short i = 0x1123;
    short* p = &i;
    
    char* c = reinterpret_cast<char*>( p );
    char* c1 = c + 1;

    std::cout << "Short: " << std::showbase << std::hex << i << '\n'
              << "p: " << p << '\n'
              << "c: "  << +( *c ) << '\n'
              << "c1: " << +( *c1 ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

There is no need for `p1`. The problem with `p1++` is that it adds 2 to the value of `p1` and not 1 as you would expect. And that's because `p1` is a pointer to `short` so when you increment it, it progresses by 2 (`short` is 2 bytes). You need to cast it to a `char*` so that each time you increment it, it will add 1 to the value.

Also, notice the `+` operator in `+( *c )`. Using this operator will make sure that `*c` won't be printed as a character but instead as its ASCII value or whatever value it has, thus there is no need to cast it to `int`.

Possible output:

```
Short: 0x1123
p: 0xb71f3ffd8e
c: 0x23
c1: 0x11
```

Comment: Nice one, thanks!

Comment: @TheOnlyWAR10CK93 Check the improved version. I replaced the static casts with the `+` operator to make the code simpler.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution that uses no pointer trix and doesn't care about endianness.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{ 
    short i = 0x1123;

    unsigned low = i % 256;
    unsigned high = i / 256;

    std::cout << std::hex
              << "Short: " << i << '\n'
              << "low: "   << low << '\n'
              << "high: "  << high << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! However the point was the prove to myself that each pointer value points to a byte, rather then to separate out the bytes from a short haha. Just the simplest example I could conceive.

Comment: Btw, the bit-operations version of this technique would be `unsigned low = i & 0xFF; unsigned high = (i>>8) & 0xFF;`

Comment: @Jeremy - Why? The compiler will figure that out anyway.

Comment: @TheOnlyWAR10CK93 - And my point was rather that you don't _need_ pointers (with potential UB) to do this. So less need to figure that out.

Comment: I know what your point was. My point was that this was an exercise in pointers.

Comment: @BoP some people prefer to do it that way; if you come across code that does it that way, it's nice to know what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to rustyx and Pete Becker who answered this. The program is aware that the pointer is for a type short therefore when I try to increment it automatically increments the value by 2. This behaviour can be circumvented by  casting the pointer to a char.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    short i = 0x1123;

    cout
        << "Short: " << hex << i << '\n'
        ;

    
    char* p = (char*)&i;        
    char c = *p;

    cout
        << "p: " << hex << (unsigned int)p << '\n'
        << "c: " << hex << (unsigned int)c << '\n'
        ;

    char* p1 = p + 1;
    char c1 = *p1;

    cout
        << "p1: " << hex << (unsigned int)p1 << '\n'
        << "c1: " << hex << (unsigned int)c1 << '\n'
        ;

    return 0;
}
```

```
Output:
Short: 1123
p: 54fd54
c: 23
p1: 54fd55
c1: 11
```